# SQL Server - best way to store large bitmask?

Tags: sql-server, bitmask

I need to store a large bitmask (potentially up to 3000 bits long) in a sql server table.

I have the data as a string of 1s and 0s.

The requirements:

- The field that I store it in needs to be indexable
- I need to be able to compare the stored value with other stored values to see if they are equal
- I do NOT need to do any bitwise operations
- I need any conversion from the bitmask to the stored value and back again to be fast
- The length of each string of 1s and 0s is unknown, but there is a max length (of 3000)
- I have millions of these to store

What is the best way to store this data? I was looking at using a varbinary field, but it doesn't seem to be particularly neat/quick ways of converting a string of bits to a hex value.

Comment: Who or what is going to do the storing and retrieval? Having client code do the translation from bytes to bitstrings doesn't seem overly burdensome. (You can write T-SQL code to do this, of course, but it's going to be hideously slow.) For testing equality on millions of large fields rapidly, you probably want a checksum/hash index rather than index the field itself. In that case you could even consider storing the bitstring as a `VARCHAR(3000)` and applying page compression to keep down the size, even though this is much less efficient than a binary column.

Comment: Hex is just a string representation of binary data. It is easy to convert the value from binary to a hex string in T-SQL with `CONVERT` but I don't know why you would want to do that if you need bits rather than characters.

Comment: I want to keep all of this in SQL if possible. I happen to have the bits as a string as the source of the data - if I can convert that to a bit array in sql and store that and still do the other requirements then that would be great - but I can't see how to do that either